# Tryng to access label of an Enum

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to access the label of an Enum, but I only find the value of each enum. Is there a way to do it?

```
export enum Filtros {
  Ligacoes = "Ligações",
  Tempo = "Tempo em chamada (min)",
  Email = "E-mails enviados",
  Reuniao = "Reuniões agendadas",
}
```

I'm passing this enum as an array to a child component:

```
interface Props {
  filtros: Filtros[];
}
```

Basically what I want to do is to create an object depinding on the enums passed to this component.

```
function makeDataSets(filtros: Filtros[]){
  let dataSets = [];
  let data = []
  let dataObj = filtros.map(filtro => {
    myObj.map(item => {for(let [key, value] of Object.entries(item)){
      if(key == filtro.???){//I can't get this part correctly...
         data.push(value)
      } 
    }})
    dataSets.push({
    label: filtro.valueOf(),
    data: 
  })})
}
```

My Object that returns from the API:

```
const dataSet = [
  {
    nome: "Bruno Schimit",
    ligações: 200,
    tempo: 456,
    emails: 23,
    reuniões: 12,
    negocios: 8,
    valorTotal: 16000,
    ticketMedio: 2000,
    backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)",
  },
  {
    nome: "Carlos Beltrão",
    ligações: 200,
    tempo: 456,
    emails: 23,
    reuniões: 12,
    negocios: 5,
    valorTotal: 25000,
    ticketMedio: 5000,
    backgroundColor: "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)",
  },
...
]
```

And of course I'm open to critics about my function...

Answer (score 0):

In TypeScript, enums are purely a compile-time abstraction, they compile down to their base primitives (in this case, strings) at runtime. Thus, there is no way to access the label of an enum.

One way to achieve what you want is to use an object to emulate one.

```
type Filtros = "Ligacoes" | "Tempo" | "Email" | "Reuniao";

const filters: Record<Filtros, string> = {
  Ligacoes: "Ligações",
  Tempo: "Tempo em chamada (min)",
  Email: "E-mails enviados",
  Reuniao: "Reuniões agendadas",
};
```

Comment: But how woudl I use it at a useState function? Like this? const [filters, setFilters] = useState<typeof filters[]>([
   ????
  ]);

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can but you have to search for it by value as you would do with objects. I will correct the one answer before me as, when compiled, enums are undefined object but with properties that you defined. You can test it in [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play). It somewhat similar to regular js objects but not exactly the same so it can be weird sometimes.

```
enum Filtros {
  Ligacoes = "Ligações",
  Tempo = "Tempo em chamada (min)",
  Email = "E-mails enviados",
  Reuniao = "Reuniões agendadas",
}

const filtros = [Filtros.Tempo]
filtros.forEach(value => {
   const label = Object.keys(Filtros).find(label => Filtros[label] === value)
   console.log(label)
})
```